# How to install debug symbols for installed packages?

Tags: debugging

I try to watch how programs work by running them by the 'Qt Creator' debugger. For better orientation I'd like to see also the system (core) utilities fully in the call stack window as I am used from the MS Visual Studio 6.0, not only to see their assembly code. For the utilities, the 'Qt Creator' debugger displays only that their debug symbols are not available. (Sometimes, the system generates bug reports for its developers; the bug report dialog has requested installing such symbols only for a particular program.) **How can I get the core debug symbols?** (Without translating the whole Ubuntu version. I use the 'Update Manager' to install updates regularly. My

```
/sys/kernel/debug/x86
```

directory contains only one empty file. I have not found it in the 'Ubuntu software center' nor do I see if some of the packages at the http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/x11/ is what I seek.) Thanks!

Comment: See [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingProgramCrash#Debug_Symbol_Packages) page.

Comment: @saiarcot895 It works, please formulate your comment as an answer so that I can set it as an accepted one. Where are the debug symbols placed in my filesystem? Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Packages in Ubuntu have their debugging symbols stored in a separate repo. To download these debugging symbols, run (copy and paste):

```
printf "deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com %s main restricted universe multiverse\n" $(lsb_release -cs){,-updates,-security,-proposed} | \
 sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ddebs.list
```

to add the repo links into `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ddebs.list` (This makes it easier to remove the repo). Alternatively, you can also copy each of the `deb` links into Software Sources and add them from there (Note that you'll likely need to replace `$(lsb_release -cs)` with the Ubuntu release that you're running).

Then, for Ubuntu 18.04 or later, you need to execute a keyring installation command:

```bash
sudo apt install ubuntu-dbgsym-keyring
```

Then, for any Ubuntu, run:

```bash
sudo apt update
```

To download the debugging symbols for `package`, you can just install `package-dbgsym` or, in some cases, `package-dbg`. Note that packages from a PPA don't have debugging symbols available from repos, and that it's the maintainer's responsibility to provide a package that contains the debugging symbols, usually in a package named `package-dbg`.

Debugging symbols are installed in `/usr/lib/debug`, although `gdb` automatically reads in debugging symbols if available and that you don't manually need to specify a location to look in. Depending on the Debhelper Compatibility version of the package, debugging symbols may either be located in a folder with the name of the build ID located inside `.build-id` (`>= 9`), or may be located relative to where the executable would be installed (`< 9`). For example, if you were looking for the location of the debugging symbols for `/usr/bin/zip`, and the version is less than 9, it would be in `/usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/zip`.

To remove all debugging symbols and the repo, run `sudo apt-get remove \.*-dbgsym` to remove all `-dbgsym` packages, and `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ddebs.list` to remove the debugging symbols repo.

Comment: Just a note that PPAs now do generate dbgsym packages.  But you need to add a deb line with "main/debug", like: "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/USER/PPA/ubuntu vivid main/debug"

Comment: As of bionic, the ddebs repo doesn't have a Release file for bionic-security

Comment: I got "E: The repository 'http://ddebs.ubuntu.com impish-security Release' does not have a Release file." after `sudo apt update` and couldn't see any dbg packages, possibly same that Paulo was referring to.

Answer (score 9):

Adding to Evans answer: On Ubuntu 18.04 and later you use the command

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-dbgsym-keyring
```

to install the GPG keys. (According to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages )

Answer (score 5):

Adding to saircot859's answer. You also have to install the GPG key for the repositories as described here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 428D7C01 C8CAB6595FDFF622
```

Comment: Linked wiki page was updated. On Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and newer, use `sudo apt install ubuntu-dbgsym-keyring`.

Answer (score 1):

**Also get the correct source code with `apt source`**

In addition to the symbols, you will also to get the source with `apt source` as mentioned at:

- [How do I get and modify the source code of packages installed through apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28372/how-do-i-get-and-modify-the-source-code-of-packages-installed-through-apt-get)
- [Error :: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496549/error-you-must-put-some-source-uris-in-your-sources-list)

and then point GDB to them with `substitute-path` as mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23868252/gdb-source-path

Some fully working commands on Ubuntu 22.04, e.g. to debug `ls` from `coreutils` follow.

First we ge the debug symbosls:

```
printf "deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com %s main restricted universe multiverse\n" $(lsb_release -cs){,-updates,-security,-proposed} | \
 sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ddebs.list
sudo apt install ubuntu-dbgsym-keyring
sudo apt update
sudo apt install coreutils-dbgsym
```

Next we get the source code as per: [Error :: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496549/error-you-must-put-some-source-uris-in-your-sources-list)

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list~
sudo sed -Ei 's/^# deb-src /deb-src /' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update
apt source coreutils
```

which produces a directory `coreutils-8.32`.

Finally we run `ls` pointing GDB to the downloaded source. On Ubuntu 22.04:

```
gdb -ex 'set substitute-path . coreutils-8.32' ls
```

On Ubuntu 23.10 I instead needed:

```
gdb -ex "set substitute-path /usr/src/coreutils-9.1-1ubuntu2 coreutils-9.1" ls
```

And now I see the source correctly as in:

```
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x4d20: file src/ls.c, line 1622.
Starting program: /usr/bin/ls 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Temporary breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffce08) at src/ls.c:1622
warning: Source file is more recent than executable.
1622    {
(gdb) l
1617      signal_setup (false);
1618    }
1619
1620    int
1621    main (int argc, char **argv)
1622    {
1623      int i;
1624      struct pending *thispend;
1625      int n_files;
1626
```

The choice of `set substitute-path .` is because without `substitute-path` it would fail with:

```
1622    src/ls.c: No such file or directory.
```

so we help GDB find the source by making it convert `.` to `coreutils-8.32/` where the `src/` lives. And on Ubuntu 23.10 the error was instead:

```
Cannot display "/usr/src/coreutils-9.1-1ubuntu2/src/ls.c" ([Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/src/coreutils-9.1-1ubuntu2/src/ls.c')
```

so now we want `/usr/src/coreutils-9.1-1ubuntu2` to be replaced with `coreutils-9.1`.

The `/usr/src` path from Ubuntu 23.10 is quite nice actually, a sane setup would be to dump all sources there so we can avoid `substitute-path` all the time. However, even if I `cd/usr/src` first even that is still broken because of the `-1ubuntu2` suffix, alas. But we could manually:

```
sudo cp -rv coreutils-9.1/ /usr/src/coreutils-9.1-1ubuntu2
```

which allows us to simply:

```
gdb ls
```

Unfortunately not all packages follow that `/usr/src` convention, e.g. on Ubuntu 23.10 `libx11-6-dbgsym` had prefix `/build/libx11-9By7Fr/libx11-1.8.6/build/src/../../src/XlibInt.c`. One day we'll get there.

**GDB step debug into glibc**

The exact same procedure works for shared libraries. E.g. to GDB step debug glibc as asked at:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48476571/get-source-code-for-libc-for-debugging-in-gdb
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/678163/how-can-i-get-glibc-libstdc-sources-and-set-them-up-for-gdb-to-find

In that case, the debug symbols already appear to come preinstalled, otherwise we would need:

```
sudo apt install libc6-dbg
```

and then get source with:

```
apt source libc6
```

which produces directory: `glibc-2.35`.

We then make a C hello world to test with:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    puts("hello");
}
```

If we try to compile, GDB and go into glibc

```
gcc -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main.out main.c
gdb main.out
```

as:

```
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x1151: file main.c, line 4.
Starting program: /home/ciro/tmp/main.out 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at main.c:4
4           puts("hello");
(gdb) s
__GI__IO_puts (str=0x555555556004 "hello") at ./libio/ioputs.c:33
33      ./libio/ioputs.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb)
```

we see that the library also searches for files under `./`, so once again we:

```
set substitute-path . glibc-2.35
```

and now we can see the source:

```
(gdb) l
28      #include <string.h>
29      #include <limits.h>
30
31      int
32      _IO_puts (const char *str)
33      {
34        int result = EOF;
35        size_t len = strlen (str);
36        _IO_acquire_lock (stdout);
37
```

Some other versions of Ubuntu had sources at an absolute location like:

```
/tmp/build138741687/
```

in which case you would instead want:

```
set substitute-path /tmp/build138741687/ glibc-2.35
```