# Which packages to install to get debugging symbols for Xorg server

Tags: xubuntu, xorg, 18.04, crash, debug

Sometimes when resuming from suspend, my screen goes black, no input is accepted, and I'm forced to hard reboot. I discovered a core file, so I ran

```
sudo gdb --core=/core
```

which output:

```
Core was generated by `/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -noliste'.
Program terminated with signal SIGBUS, Bus error.
```

There was no info in */var/log/Xor.0.log.old*, apport generated a crash report under */var/crash* but I couldn't decypher any meaningful info from it, */var/log/apport.log* had a suspicious entry for the time of the crash:

```
ERROR: apport (pid 2725) Sat Jun  2 06:11:13 2018: is_closing_session(): no DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in environment
```

My graphics card uses driver **i915** from package *xserver-xorg-video-intel*, so I installed ***xserver-xorg-video-intel-dbg*** to have its debugging symbols. All web pages about X debugging recommended installing ***xserver-xorg-core-dbg***, but this package doesn't exist since Ubuntu 16.04, and I haven't found any equivalent package.

Does anybody know what package to install to get X core debugging symbols ?

Comment: You're addressing the wrong problem. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: @waltinator, thanks for the link: I've just gone through it, there's a wealth of tips there. However, I have no problems booting: Xorg crashes when I resume from suspend, and I know it's crashing because it leaves a core behind, and apport generates a crash report confirming it.

Answer (score 1):

For intermittent X crash with SIGBUS on 18.04, please check this answer:

[Ubuntu 18.04 error on waking up from sleep : Read-error on swap device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035208/ubuntu-18-04-error-on-waking-up-from-sleep-read-error-on-swap-device/1050201#1050201)

---

P.S. I think you wanted `xserver-xorg-core-dbgsym`

I found this on the list of packages on https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server

Comment: xserver-xorg-core-dbgsym is not in the Bionic repositories. But then again, thanks to your pointer, the problem is not with the X server, so the X debugging symbols will not be needed anymore.

Comment: @PauloMarcelCoelhoAragão Debug symbols are in a separate repository. See https://askubuntu.com/a/487567/44179

Comment: Bingo ! Thank you so much, @Seth, I've just added that repo to my sources, and indeed xserver-xorg-core-dbgsym is installable now. There was a minor glitch with https://askubuntu.com/a/487567/44179: bionic-security doesn't have a Release file, so only bionic and bionic-updates are available.