# Prompt is marching across the screen when entering gdb TUI

Tags: command-line, gdb

I'm debugging a program:

```
// t.c
#include <assert.h>

int main() {
    assert(0);
    return 0;
}
```

```
gcc t.c -g
gdb ./a.out
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/user/a.out 
a.out: t.c:4: main: Assertion `0' failed.

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
50  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb)
```

When entering TUI by `ctrl-x a` and `up` to check upper frame, it's a mess. The prompts are supposed to be aligned but now the it's marching across the screen:

[image: gdb]

Even leaving gdb and returning back to bash, the output is still a mess.

I'm using `gdb 9.2` and `ubuntu 20.04`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install debug symbols for installed packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487222/how-to-install-debug-symbols-for-installed-packages)

Comment: @N0rbert isn't the OP's question about why the prompt is marching across the screen?

Comment: You've tagged this `bash` - however I think what is more important is the *terminal emulator* that you are using. Is this WSL by any chance?

Comment: Sorry for my late response. Yes, I'm asking about the messy prompt. They're supposed to be aligned but now they're out of order. I'm not using WSL. I edited the question to make it more clear.