# "Report a Problem" Window Details to clipboard

Tags: bug-reporting, clipboard

I have received a desktop notification stating that an application has stopped unexpectedly, am prompted to decide whether or not to send the details of this crash to the developers, which of course I will do, but I want to keep a .txt file of all of these details for me to look over later, learning the meaning of, improve my understanding of the Linux OS to put it in a general way.

It allows me to highlight particular detail fields, but ctrl+C does not copy the text to the clipboard, nor am I able to right click on it. If obtaining a text copy isn't possible, then I will just take screen shots but of course a .txt file will be much better.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue that's been reported since 2014: https://bugs.launchpad.net/apport/+bug/1273752
So, in essence, the tool does not allow copying, unfortunately.

For the time being, you can use tools like `apport-unpack` to extract useful information from the `.crash` file in `/var/`.

See for example [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/947532/29270) on how to do it.

Comment: Ok thanks i no longer use ubuntu so hopefully this answer applies to all debian based OS, ideally, what i want is something that logs a VM of the OS i already have or intend to do a physical install of on a machine, and when i said log i really should have said LOGS,  for every process from boot to crash, one for every layer of abstraction, for machine code, for assembly all the way up to the highest level language used

Comment: So essentially, i want to be able to intentionally crash and or ruin a virtual install of the OS, and have all of its activity logs piped to another computer via ssh aas i do so