# System program problem detected?

Tags: 18.04

I keep getting, since several days, "System program problem detected" error message:

[image]

I always clicked on Report problem button but nothing happens.

I also run update and upgrade everyday.

What causes this ? How to get rid of it ?

Comment: are you only interested in getting rid of this message? here is the solution : https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/disable-apport-error-reporting-ubuntu-16-04-lts
if this satisfies you i'll make an answer. this is something I (and many others) always do right after a fresh install of ubuntu.

Comment: Indeed, it is worth to summarize what is mentioned in that link.

Comment: @begueradj Did you have Bleachbit on your box when you got this message. I believe that this error started for me after I upgraded to Bleachbit 4.0.0?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

> What causes this ?

See the crash report that is dumped on your disk. The directory you want is `/var/crash/` and it will contain several files pointing you to the package it is about and what the crash is.

This directory is described as:

> [/var/crash](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/fhs-2.3.html#VARCRASHSYSTEMCRASHDUMPS) : System crash dumps (optional)
>
> This directory holds system crash dumps. As of the date of this release of the standard, system crash dumps were not supported under
>   Linux but may be supported by other systems which may comply with the
>   FHS.

Ubuntu releases use this (optional) directory to dump crashes and the package that does that is called [apport](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport) (and [whoopsie)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ErrorTracker). The link has a detailed description and also has a PDF that describes the crash report [data format](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=data-format.pdf).

If you want really detailed reports on a crash install [GDB: The GNU Project Debugger](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) with `sudo apt-get install gdb`.

---

> How to get rid of it ?

Depends on what you call "get rid". The ideal fix would be to check what is inside the reports, and try and find a fix for it. If the package it is about is unneeded or benign you could also purge it. Most times it is a core functionality though.

If you can not understand those crash reports most times you can google the error notice (there will always be one in there). Or drop a message in chat. Generally crashes are off topic on AU as those are bugs and would need to be reported (through this service ;) ).

You can pick any of these to remove the crash report up to actually removing the package (would be rather ironic if the error comes from apport itself):

- `sudo rm /var/crash/*` will delete old crashes and stop informing you about them until some package crashes again.
- You can stop the service with `sudo systemctl disable apport` (and enable it again with `sudo systemctl enable apport`)
- If you do not want to see crash reports you can disable it by doing `sudo vim /etc/default/apport`  and changing`enabled=1` to `enabled=0`. (or `sudo nano /etc/default/apport`). Editing it in reverse will enable it again.
- You can delete the service with `sudo apt purge apport` (and install it again with `sudo apt install apport`)
- And there is also a desktop method (option "problem reporting":

[image]

---

[how to read and use crash reports?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346953/how-to-read-and-use-crash-reports) has some interesting answers. It has an example crash report and a method to retrace crashes.

Comment: The question is, why clicking "report problem" does nothing, so old crash reports still trigger the window on each restart. So a mention of what is the intended flow would be best as the first way of getting rid of that window.

Comment: I am seeing this error on lubuntu 18.04. My `/var/crash` folder exists, but it is empty. Also, I doubt that `gdb` would be of much use in debugging, unless you know which program is crashing.

Comment: I'd call this answer: ***"Everything you wanted to know about system crash but were afraid to ask"***.

Comment: why nothing happens after clicking the report button.

Comment: For me it's the Xorg https://gist.github.com/Pacheco95/4f319d69b3d5f64d608897b77f31f355
Have no idea how to fix this

Comment: @MichaelPacheco It shows a permission denied so either there is a need for sudo at the command issued or the system is lacking a directory the package needs but  does not create itself. 1st step would be to make sure the package is meant for your system :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I must say that this is a really *terrible* interface. No hint of what is happening, what to do about it, how to fix it. And it just keeps reappearing. Now I've deleted these files, and will have to see if this was just a "stuck" report. "2024 is the year of Linux on the desktop", huh? ;-)

Answer (score 11):

Apport is an ubuntu functionality which reports errors in ubuntu.

it is non-critical and can be safely disabled without any adverse effects.

it's purpose is to aid Ubuntu devs in identifing issues as they occur on user's PCs

#### How to disable apport:

you must edit a file:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/apport
```

and replace the `1` with a `0`

like so :

[image: disableing apport]

then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>Y</kbd> to save.

If you don't want to reboot to apply you can disable it on the spot:

```
sudo systemctl disable apport
```

You may also completely uninstall apport:

```
sudo apt purge apport
```

After that you will no longer see this window.

More usefull information can be found here :https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/disable-apport-error-reporting-ubuntu-16-04-lts

Comment: Will this just get rid of the popups or will it also prevent the crash reports from appearing in `/var/crash`?

Comment: which one? It's certain that if you do `sudo apt purge apport` you have no more crash entries in `/var/crash` as well as no popups whereas the edit of `/etc/default/apport` i think only disables the popup, but it might also do both.

Comment: why nothing happens after clicking the report button.

Comment: thanks a lot, this is gold: due to a project and a simulation platform made for Ubuntu, I had to return to this system, and seeing this dialogue so many times was really staring to break my nerves

Answer (score 7):

What I suggest is that you delete these crash reports. Open a terminal and use the following command:

```
sudo rm /var/crash/*
```

Comment: why nothing happens after clicking the report button.

Answer (score 3):

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.5 with Mate 1.24.0.

I was getting this message on every boot. I installed `apport` and `apport-retrace` and applied `apport-retrace` to the crash files I found in `/var/crash`. However, in all cases the program complained that something was missing.  In most cases this was just "Package", and did not reveal anything else. I suspect that this is why "Report Problem" is unresponsive.

Since I couldn't get any information from the crash files, I examined `/var/log/dmesg` and found two boot errors.  The first being ...

> `Unable to communicate with TPM chip`

This is potentially the most serious. In the BIOS, I hid the chip.  On reboot the message ...

> `System program problem detected`

... appeared, but `dmesg` showed a more benign warning about being unable to find a TPM device.

To test whether the problem was in going to X, I deleted `/var/log/dmesg`, `/var/log/syslog`, and `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and then rebooted the display manager using `sudo systemctl restart display-manager`. No new syslog was produced and the new `dmesg` and `Xorg.0` logs only showed minor warnings.

I then deleted all of the `/var/crash` files and rebooted. This time the *"System program problem detected"* was not reported. Obviously, this message is inspired by old crash files even if they are no longer relevant.

My conclusion is use this message to alert you that there may be a boot problem but immediately delete the `/var/crash/` files and try to fix serious errors you find in `/var/log/dmesg`, as well as potentially `syslog` and `Xorg.0`.

Comment: On a related note, I believe I have found the most bad*ss markdown cheatsheet ever in existence: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/325826 You can access the raw markdown text by clicking "Improve this answer" under the post (even without logging in). The raw text then can be copied for studying from the textarea that appears.