# System Software Problem detected: Toshiba Satellite NB10t-A

Tags: crash, bug-reporting

I've got a little touchscreen netbook. It's a little dated. It's a Toshiba Satellite NB10t-A, Model #PU141C-02Y020. I've upgraded its' hard drive to a 250GB Western Digital Blue SSD, and I've maxed out this poor little Bay Trail processor's RAM to 8GB. It's actually pretty good now, considering it only has a 2.2 GHz dual-core. It used to run Win10 (prior to my hardware upgrades), and it was really struggling with just 4GB of ram - so I installed Ubuntu 18.04. The performance gains were encouraging, so I went through with the hardware upgrades and reinstalled. In both instances, I ran into a System Software Problem detected notification.
[image]

I was hoping someone here could give me hand getting a grasp on what the problem might be. It would be a fun challenge to get it resolved. It doesn't cause the system to fail, but something is crashing upon startup.

I saw some good information in another post (below).
[Another similar thread, click here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1160113/system-program-problem-detected#_=_)

But I think I'm going to need a hand with this one. I have no real coding knowledge but I'm a little familiar with Terminal. If there's anything the community could talk me through - I'm kinda stuck indoors atm! How would I go about getting the contents of my crash folder in front of the community?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a problem with an older computer, with an older GPU. Try this...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf` # edit this file

change:

#WaylandEnable=false

to:

WaylandEnable=false

Save the file and quit `gedit`. Then reboot.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the reply. Will this change anything for me as an end user?

Comment: Quick report back... I followed the provided steps. Terminal reported several errors. I did save gedit and close it and reopen it again to confirm the change. Then rebooted. Still got the popup. Are you sure there isn't a typo (to confirm: was I just to remove the hashtag? #

Comment: The `gedit` errors are just noise, and if you rechecked your work, you're fine. If the popup that you mention is for the Wayland crash, that happens some times, and we have to manually delete the old crash files in `terminal` with the command `sudo rm -i /var/crash/*.crash`. Reboot and you shouldn't see the popup any more. In the future, if you do see those kind of popups, be sure to either click SEND REPORT, or DON'T SEND REPORT, don't just close the window. If my answer ends up solving the problem for you, please accept it by clicking the checkmark icon. Thanks!

Comment: ok. I'll see about deleting the old crash files. And, yes, I definitely click Send Report each time it happens. Thanks for the help, between this thread and the other thread linked, I think I should be ok. Once I'm sorted, I'll confirm your answer.

Comment: Success! Thus far I'm crash report free. Thanks again.