# System Problem Detected Ubuntu 18.04 due to drive mount

Tags: boot, mount, automount

I am using ubuntu 18.04 on Acer Predator Helios 300 PH-315-51, every time my system boots up it prompts me with a message `System problem detected` i noticed it is actually due to the auto drive mount at startup, if i disable auto drive mount then it does not prompts me with this message, i don't know why is this happening. Can anyone please explain why is it so and how can i fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo rm /var/crash/*`. This will clear all the crash reports if there are any. If this does not solve the issue try reviewing the logs.

Here, is a reference with a similar problem:

1. [System program problem detected?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1160113/system-program-problem-detected)