# Crashes in gpk-update-viewer and lightdm after upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: upgrade, lightdm, crash

Today I upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04, using `do-release-upgrade`.  The upgrade appeared to go successfully.  (No errors during the upgrade.)

However, now, every time that I log in, I get this super-helpful error message:

[image: System program problem detected]

Apparently, this actually means [go look in /var/crash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1160113/system-program-problem-detected).  So, I looked in `/var/crash` and this is what I found:

```
ppelleti@patrick64:~$ ls -lht /var/crash
total 1.6M
-rw-r----- 1 root     whoopsie 297K Sep 21 18:44 _usr_sbin_lightdm.0.crash
-rw-r----- 1 ppelleti whoopsie 1.3M Sep 21 18:43 _usr_bin_gpk-update-viewer.1000.crash
-rw------- 1 whoopsie whoopsie    0 Sep 21 17:11 _usr_bin_gpk-update-viewer.1000.uploaded
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ppelleti whoopsie    0 Sep 21 17:11 _usr_bin_gpk-update-viewer.1000.upload
ppelleti@patrick64:~$
```

So it appears that `lightdm` and `gpk-update-viewer` are crashing.  The two `.crash` files are huge; what should I look for in them to help diagnose the problem?

Thanks!