# I always greet "System program problem detected" message when I login in ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, system

My ubuntu version:20.04 LTS

Yesterday, I try to connect my airpods, but my airpods is out of power, the system reports "System program problem detected" message. I don't pay a lot of attention to it, But since that, I usually greet this message when I start my computer, I can connect my airpods still by the way. I try to find the solutions, but most of them seems like just ignore it. I run `ls -l` to check what's in the `/var/crash` directory:

```
total 22040
-rw-r----- 1 faye     whoopsie 9809808 Feb  8 18:00 _usr_bin_minecraft-launcher.1000.crash
-rw-rw-r-- 1 faye     whoopsie       0 Feb  8 18:00 _usr_bin_minecraft-launcher.1000.upload
-rw------- 1 whoopsie whoopsie      37 Feb  8 18:01 _usr_bin_minecraft-launcher.1000.uploaded
-rw-r----- 1 faye     whoopsie 2868360 Feb  7 23:56 _usr_bin_onedrive.1000.crash
-rw-r----- 1 root     whoopsie 2343968 Feb  9 18:28 _usr_lib_bluetooth_bluetoothd.0.crash
-rw-r----- 1 faye     whoopsie 7440784 Feb  3 11:37 _usr_lib_ibus-rime_ibus-engine-rime.1000.crash
-rw-rw-r-- 1 faye     whoopsie       0 Feb  3 11:37 _usr_lib_ibus-rime_ibus-engine-rime.1000.upload
-rw------- 1 whoopsie whoopsie      37 Feb  3 11:38 _usr_lib_ibus-rime_ibus-engine-rime.1000.uploaded
-rw-r----- 1 faye     whoopsie   86443 Feb  8 18:00 _usr_lib_update-notifier_backend_helper.py.1000.crash
```

There is a minecraft launcher crash, but this is a dependency problem, I already fixed it by run `sudo apt-get install -f` command.
Seems like my computer works well, should I run `sudo rm /var/crash/*` to stop ubuntu informing me these messages again? Or try something else to fix my system?

So much thanks for helping me to solve this problem, and please forgive my poor English :D

Comment: Does this answer your questions? [System program problem detected?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1160113/system-program-problem-detected)

Comment: I was seeing this constantly on Ubuntu MATE 18.04 which I was using on my old computer. Previously I had Ubuntu 10.04 on this computer for a long time, but probably the hardware was too weak for 18.04 - I had constantly issues with it.

Comment: This problem is different from [System program problem detected?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1160113/system-program-problem-detected) I think this problem depends on the specific crash information