# 'System Program Problem Detected' vs "Sorry, Ubuntu * has experienced an internal error"

Tags: apport

I am trying to fix a 20 04 installation that crashes a lot.

One question i have is about the two different messages from ...(apport it seems) .
It seems sometimes i see one, sometimes the other...

[image]

[image]

I guess they are triggered by different subsystems, refer to different classes/securities of errors or so...

What is the difference here?

I found this post https://itsfoss.com/how-to-fix-system-program-problem-detected-ubuntu/
explaining how to simply suppress them, but that's not what i want.

I want to understand the origins of the two messages, and if/how they are connected.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash`. Also, when you see the 2nd type of error message, click on the Show Details button, and screenshot that. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Thanks @heynnema. I would be very grateful for help on fixing the actual problems. These are detailed in another post, which already has links (in the comments) to .crash pastebins:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280944/gnome-shell-crashes-intermittently-sends-me-back-to-login
This question here is just an offspring of it. I wonder why ubuntu shows two types of crash-notifying windows, what their origins, differences etc. are.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gnome shell crashes intermittently, sends me back to login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280944/gnome-shell-crashes-intermittently-sends-me-back-to-login)

Comment: Please don't ask duplicate questions for the same problem. Please delete this question.

Comment: @heynnema, did you overlook my answer to your first comment?
To rephrase:
My question here is nothing like "help me fix my ubuntu", but an offspring of it, "What's the difference of those error windows..."

Comment: Yes I did see it. Duplicate question. Please see my comment there.

Comment: @heynnema, I don't see how these are duplicate questions. They are triggered by the same problem of mine, yes. But that's it i think.