# LibreOffice Calc crashed very often every day in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: libreoffice

I have just moved from Xubuntu 21.10 to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. The same old LibreOffice Calc files worked so well in Xubuntu but crashed too often in Ubuntu. How can I track the cause of the crash ? I had to use Ubuntu for only one reason of Pop Shell for auto tiling. And [this is my computer](https://youtu.be/QtUzmEH-5Lk) dual booting with Windows 11 Pro. The LibreOffice Calc crashed on either version 7.3.3.2 or previous version.

Comment: Pease [edit] your question with information about the version of LO being used on your 22.04 LTS system but check first using `Software Updater` that your system is up to date. This morning there was an update to LO 7.3.3.2 with the Linux 5.15 environment. You can view crash reports - see [this Q&A from AU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346953/how-to-read-and-use-crash-reports#496895)

Comment: Same here, still crashing. Not just calc, but the file manager and Firefox too.